# How to spy window resize event using sinonjs and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jasmine, sinon

I use backbonejs, requirejs to make my javascript app.

Also I use jasmine, sinonjs and jasmine-sinon plugin to test my application but there is a problem in using spy.

The spied method is called well (I'm sure) but jasmine test result says that the method is **NOT** called!

---

I have a backbone view which has a callback for the browser window resize event.

What I want to do is to test that the 'windowResizeCallback' function should be called when window resize event is fired.

Here's my backbone view code.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'use!underscore',
    'use!backbone',
    // other dependencies..
], function (
    $,
    _,
    Backbone,
    // other dependencies..
) {

    var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function () {
            // do initialization
            var self = this;
            $(window).resize($.proxy(self.windowResizeCallback, self));
        },

        windowResizeCallback: function () {
            // do my business..
            this.otherFunction();
        },

        otherFunction: function () {
            // function called by window resize callback
        }

        // other properties, functions, ..

    });

    return MyView;
});
```

Here's my test code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jasmine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/sinon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jasmine-sinon.js"></script>
<!-- other scripts.. -->
<script type="text/javascript>
define([
    'view/myView'
], function (
    MyView
) {

    describe('view.MyView', function () {

        beforeEach(function () {
            this.view = new MyView();
            sinon.spy(this.view, 'windowResizeCallback');
        });

        afterEach(function () {
            this.view.windowResizeCallback.restore();
        });

        describe('MyView.windowResizeCallback', function () {

            beforeEach(function () {
                this.view.windowResizeCallback.reset();
            });

            it('callback should be called when window resize event fired', function () {
                $(window).trigger('resize');
                expect(this.view.windowResizeCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
                // above test fails !!!!
            });

        });
    });

});
</script>
```

I think that the test code should be passed but it fails with an error

```
Expected Function to have been called.
```

When I insert an alert code inside the 'windowResizeCallback' method, alert appears well so I believe that the callback is called well when the browser window resize event is fired.

I couldn't understand why. Is there anything wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the event listener use the original function. First you initialize the view, the event listener is bound to the original function, then you replace the `windowResizeCallback` function in the view but the function that is bound to the event listener is still the original function.

Also its not a good idea to spy/sub/mock functions of the object you wanna test. Better test the result of the `windowResizeCallback` function.

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem myself but your answer is helpful for clearing up the situation.

Comment: But I cannot fully understand what 'Better test the result of the windowResizeCallback function' means. If it is not a good idea to spy the object, then how can I improve my codes? Can you explain about it more?

Comment: Think about your View as a black box where you put some stuff in and you should not test that the view calls internal functions to change the the stuff, but to test that something was done with the stuff. So spy on the dependencies of your view (like the model or the el) not on the view itself.

Comment: Roger. Thanks a lot Andreas!